# How to prevent MKPolygons from overlapping in MKMapView

Tags: swift, mapkit, overlap, mkoverlay, mkpolygon

I have a set of MKPolygons to be drawn in my MKMapView but they end up overlapping each other, which brings the aspect of a patchwork, like in the image below.

Is that a way to combine multiple MKPolygons into a single MKPolygon instance, merging their paths so the overlay would look like a single layer, instead of a patchwork of small layers?

I have already tried [MKPolygon-GPC](https://github.com/SunGard-Labs/MKPolygon-GPC) but it hasn't worked properly in my tests.

Any thoughts?

[image: MKPolygons overlapping]

Comment: Were you able to find any solutions?

Comment: Not really, @TheRedCamaro3.03.0